# Solving a system of first order ODEs with DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve a system of firrst order ODEs with symbolic coefficients. However, when I try to evaluate my `DSolve` expression, Mathematica's output is to simply return the `DSolve` expression.

My code, is

```
q[t_] = Subscript[p, 0]*Cos[α*t] + Subscript[p, 0]*Sin[α*t];
p[t_] = Subscript[p, 0]*Cos[α*t] - Subscript[q, 0]*Sin[α*t];
X11[t_] = β * q[t]*p[t];
X12[t_] = ϵ + (β/2)*(q[t]^2 + p[t]^2) + β*p[t]^2;
X21[t_] = -(ϵ + (β/2)*(q[t]^2 + p[t]^2) + β*
  q[t]^2);
X22[t_] = -X11[t];
system = {u'[t] - X11[t]*u[t] - X12[t]*v[t] , v'[t] - X21[t]*u[t] - X22[t]*v[t]};
sol = DSolve[{system[[1]] == 0, system[[2]] == 0}, {u, v}, t]
```

- How can I ask Mathematica to display the analytical solution?

Comment: "Mathematica gives as output the command `DSolve`" - it means that *Mathematica* doesn't know how to find a closed form solution for your DEs, if it does have one.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that an analytical solution exists in the first place?

Comment: My first thought was based on the fact the system is made by two first order linear equations. Then, may have a solution (analytical). However, I did further investigation and it seems it hasn't an analytical solution. Thanks